# How can clear all tables in ActiveAndroid?

Tags: android, activeandroid

I have about 20-30 tables in my `ActiveAndroid` database. When I press `logoutButton` I want to clear all the tables. How can I do it in `ActiveAndroid`?

```
 public void logOut() {
     //clear all tables
 }
```

Comment: You are asking for a complete solution. This is encouraged on Stackoverflow. Instead, write your own code and when you encounter a problem, (1) search for an answer, (2) only ask if you have not found it.

Comment: I ask a specific question. how to clean the base.

Comment: Delete the database file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = ActiveAndroid.getDatabase();
        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String tableName = cursor.getString(1);
            if (!tableName.equals("android_metadata") &&
                    !tableName.equals("sqlite_sequence")) {
                tables.add(tableName);
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        for (String tableName : tables) {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
        }
```

Comment: Good. I have all names of my tables. How can i clear this tables?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add deleting

Comment: I'm getting a `SQLiteConstraintException` because I have a foreign key between some of my tables. Any solution to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this could help someone using Active Android.**

for deleting all the records in a table there is an easy way.

1) First Create class "TruncatableModel" and extend all your Models  to this class

```
public abstract class TruncatableModel extends Model {
    public static void truncate(Class<? extends Model> type){
        final String tableName = Cache.getTableInfo(type).getTableName();

        // Delete all rows from table
        ActiveAndroid.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM %s;", tableName));

        // Reset ids
        ActiveAndroid.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='%s';", tableName));
    }
}
```

.. so after extending, my model class would look like.

```
@Table(name = "note")
public class Note extends TruncatableModel {
    @Column(name ="idn")
    public Integer idn;
    @Column(name ="title")
    public String title;
    ...
}
```

2)  Now i can delete all the records in "note" database using this code.

```
Note.truncate(Note.class);
```

This seems to be more efficient way than any other methods i have tried.